# How can I solve the problem with ReplyKeyboardButton?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have a problem with the method ReplyKeyboardButton.

I tried to connect the module from the aiogram, i tried to take types from telebot, i tried to use only one module (telebot)

```
import telebot
#from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
#ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    #InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

token = 'mytoken'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

#keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
#keyboard1.row('Категории', 'Купить приватку', 'Что дает приватка?')
button_qiwi = ReplyKeyboardButton('QIWI')
button_sber = ReplyKeyboardButton('Сбербанк')
button_categories = ReplyKeyboardButton('Категории')
button_privat = ReplyKeyboardButton('Купить приватку')
button_whatis = ReplyKeyboardButton('Что дает приватка?')
button_cancel = ReplyKeyboardButton('Назад')

markup_start = ReplyKeyboardMarkup().row(
    button_categories, button_privat, button_whatis
)

markup_pay = ReplyKeyboardMarkup().row(
    button_qiwi, button_sber, button_cancel
)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Чтобы ты взаимодействовал с     ботом, тебе нужно зайти в кнопки.', reply_markup=markup_start)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['sticker'])
def sticker_id(message):
    print(message)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'категории':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '123')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'купить приватку':
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAADAgADZgkAAnlc4gmfCor5YbYYRAI')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Хорошо! Приватка стоит 450 рублей. Оплатить можно через QIWI и через Сбербанк. Как удобней?', reply_markup = markup_pay)
        if message.text.lower() == 'Сбербанк':
            bot.send_text(message.chat.id, '123')
        if message.text.lower() == 'QIWI':
            bot.send_text(message.chat.id, '123')
        elif message.text.lower() == 'Назад':
            bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id,'',reply_markup = markup_start)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ой! Что-то пошло не так((')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'что дает приватка?':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Доступ ко всем категориям, Уникальный контент')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неизвестная команда')

bot.polling()
```

**This is output:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:/Users/yaros/Desktop/bot/bot.py", line 11, in 
>         button_qiwi = ReplyKeyboardButton('QIWI')
>     NameError: name 'ReplyKeyboardButton' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1.

Comment: You probably have to `import` it somewhere - looking at the rest of your code, wouldn't a `from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardButton` be what you need?

Comment: I had to remove the prefix Reply

Answer (score 0):

well, you need like `markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()`, and you have just `markup_pay = ReplyKeyboardMarkup().row`. I mean that you **forgot** about `types.` and you need `from telebot import types`